# Здравствуйте не могу вывести в боте больше 5 кнопок, в чем причина? ВК бот

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

вот мой код на PHP:

РАБОЧИЙ ВАРИАНТ но ТОЛЬКО 5.

```
  function getBtn($label, $color, $payload = '') {
    return [
        'action' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            "payload" => json_encode($payload, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
            'label' => $label
        ],
        'color' => $color
    ];
}

$keyboard = [
    'one_time' => false,
    'buttons' => [
        [
            getBtn("1", 'negative', '1'),
            getBtn("2", 'negative', '2'),
            getBtn("3", 'negative', '3'),

        ],
        [
            getBtn("4", 'negative', '4'),
            getBtn("5", 'negative', '5'),
        ],
    ]
];
```

скриншоты:
https://prnt.sc/p7vs1z
https://prnt.sc/p7vsck

вот так не срабатывает:

```
 $keyboard = [
    'one_time' => false,
    'buttons' => [
        [
            getBtn("1", 'negative', '1'),
            getBtn("2", 'negative', '2'),
            getBtn("3", 'negative', '3'),

        ],
        [
            getBtn("4", 'negative', '4'),
            getBtn("5", 'negative', '5'),
            getBtn("6", 'negative', '6'),
        ],
    ]
];
```

---

> Вы не тот код приводите. Вам нужно показывать код, с помощью которого
>   вы **выводите**, но не получается. Потому что приведенный код только
>   формирует массив, а не выводит что-либо. А формирует он вполне себе
>   http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab2a7ef5354273a2490cf211aa2eb9d7931bf0c8

как раз таки тот, потому что добавив 6 тую кнопку я получаю то что бот молчит, убираю 6тую начинает работать.

Отправка кнопки происходит так:

```
   $request_params = array(
        'message' => "Привет",
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'keyboard' => json_encode($keyboard),
        'v' => '5.50'
    );

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);

file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params);
```

Comment: Вы не тот код приводите. Вам нужно показывать код, с помощью которого вы **выводите**, но не получается. Потому что приведенный код только формирует массив, а не выводит что-либо. А формирует он вполне себе http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab2a7ef5354273a2490cf211aa2eb9d7931bf0c8

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал ваш код, почти не меняя (удалил запятые после функций в конце массива клавиатуры), все шесть кнопок отображает корректно.
Результат и [код](https://pastebin.com/j7ET44XH), можете попробовать и сравнить:

[image: Результат]

Comment: Данный ответ мне не очень то помог, ситуация продолжалась. 6 кнопок все так же не работали.

И так проблема была в том что сообщения превышает количество символов, убираю буквально два слова из текста (любых) и сразу 6 кнопок работают, но вот больше уже не могу. Если еще пол текста удалю будет и 8. Но за ответ все равно спасибо

Comment: Извиняюсь что не смог помочь, но рад что ситуация разрешилась!

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вам такой вариант.

**Функция:** (Создание клавиатуры)

```
class Keyboard
{
    private $keyboard;
    public function __construct($runtime)
    {
        $this->keyboard = array ('one_time' => $runtime, 'buttons' => array());
    }
    
    public function addButton ($label, $color, $lvl_row, $lvl_coll)
    {
        $button = [
            "action" => [
                "type" => "text",
                "label" => $label
            ],
            "color" => $color
        ];
        $this->keyboard['buttons'][$lvl_row][$lvl_coll] = $button;
    }
    
    public function getKeyboard ()
    {
        return $this->keyboard;
    }
}
```

**Функция:** (Отправка клавиатуры)

```
class MessageSendKeyboard
{  
    public function send ($msg, $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token)
    {   
        $request_params = array(
            "peer_id" => $user_id,
            "random_id" => "0",
            "message" => $msg,
            "keyboard" => json_encode($keyboard, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
            "access_token" => $access_token,
            "v" => "5.103");
        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
        file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?".$get_params);
    }
}
```

**Пример реализации:**

```
$mk = new MessageSendKeyboard();
$oKeyboard = new Keyboard(false);
    
$oKeyboard->addButton("Foo", "positive", 0, 0);
$oKeyboard->addButton("Bar", "primary", 0, 1);
$oKeyboard->addButton("Foo Bar", "negative", 1, 0);
$oKeyboard->addButton("Bar Foo»", "positive", 1, 1);
$oKeyboard->addButton("Foo Foo", "secondary", 1, 2);
$oKeyboard->addButton("Bar Bar", "secondary", 2, 0);

$keyboard = $oKeyboard->getKeyboard();
$mk->send("Hello World", $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]